# Parsing XML coming from AWS using listObjectsV2

Tags: php, xml, amazon-web-services, parsing

I am currently making api calls to S3 using PHP and the result always comes as XML.
My requests are saved into $result:

```
$results = $s3Client->listObjectsV2([
                         ...
```

How could I parse `$results` selecting only the `Key` field?

I have tried using a foreach loop but I seems like it does not work right.

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
        echo $result['Key'];
        

        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the contents:

```
foreach ($results['Contents']  as $object) {

            echo $object['Key'] . PHP_EOL;
        }
```